# What is the source of the double-dollar sign selector query function in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2PMc/), and have a look at the console. `$$` is not defined. Now, open a completely new window, and enter `$$` into a console. It defines a function for getting a (jquery-like) array of all the dom elements which match the selector:

`> $$`

```js
bound: function () {
  return document.querySelectorAll.apply(document, arguments)
}
```

Is this being added by Dev tools? It is also present when using Firebug in Firefox. Is it used internally by the tools themselves?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) defines this as:

```
this.$$=function(selector,doc){if(doc||!FBL.Firebug.chrome){return FBL.Firebug.Selector(selector,doc)
```

([See the source](https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js).)

The full version of Firebug [defines](http://code.google.com/codesearch#KtWDMkyrfDU/trunk/content/firebug/commandLineAPI.js&l=13) this as

```
this.$$ = function(selector)
{
    return FBL.getElementsBySelector(baseWindow.document, selector);
};
```

This is actually [documented](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24.24.28selector.29) and yes, it is used internally as well.

So I assume that Google Chrome is doing something similar.

Comment: I thought this might be the case.. Can anyone check the chrome source as well before I mark correct?

Comment: @minikomi - Google Chrome is not open source, so unless someone from Google can chime-in, we need to resort to looking at Chromium.  I checked-out the source for this, but can't immediately find any similar references.  However, I'm guessing it's possible that this exists in Chrome but not Chromium...

Comment: Good point. I got as far as google code but forgot the search was taken down.. However, since the two return pretty much identical functions it's safe to assume it's the source! Thank you!

Answer (score 191):

Firstly, everything in ziesemer's answer is correct.

### This is all about JavaScript history

There are a number of functions that are available in various browser's devtools consoles. Collectively, the methods are known as the [Command Line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API)(off-line) ([new link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)) and they all originate from Firebug. Nowadays we just have parity across browsers because Firebug did things (mostly) right.

But back when Firebug was being created (2006), the JavaScript library that was all the rage was Prototype.js. `$` was grabbed by Prototype for some `getElementById()` syntactic sugar as that was certainly the quickest way to be grabbing elements and most common element acquisition technique at the time. It was such a timesaver, folks used [the whole library just for the $ sugar](http://abcdefu.wordpress.com/2006/12/27/prototypejs/).

In early 2006, jQuery then debuted and used `$()` for selecting any element based on css selector. As my old [CSS Selector Engine Timeline post](http://paulirish.com/2008/javascript-css-selector-engine-timeline/) shows, Prototype then followed up **four days later** with their own, but as `$` was already taken in their library they just went to `$$()`, which is now known as **the bling-bling function**.

So Firebug was leveraging Prototype's API as it was still ruling the roost in 2006. Now, in the days of jQuery and post-jQuery aliasing like `window.$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)`, we see it as quite backwards. Interestingly, when Opera revolutionized Dragonfly, their browser dev tools, they chose `$` as their `querySelectorAll` alias, to better match present day practices, which IMO makes a bit more sense.

### Oh you meant the *code* source..

Now, you asked about the "source" of the `$$` in DevTools and I explained the history. Whoops! As to why it's available in your console... all of the [Command Line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API)(off-line) ([new link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference)) methods are available only within the context of your console, just as convenience methods.

- [Chrome DevTools'/WebKit Inspector's cmd line API source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js)
- [Firebug's cmd line API source](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/console/commandLineAPI.js)
- <s>[Opera Dragonfly's cmd line API source](https://bitbucket.org/scope/dragonfly-stp-1/src/f6b4cef0c438/src/repl/commandtransformer.js)</s>

`copy()` is one of my favorites; I cover it and others in this [JavaScript Console for Power Users](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mf_yNLlgic) video.

Comment: Ah the ambiguity of English.. I did mean the historical source, but am glad it allowed both answers. Thank again!

Comment: Those last few links are broken.

Comment: Browser source code changes quickly, so deep links are doomed to get stale. The link contents can be used together with code search tools to find the source code.

The relevant code for Chrome's DevTools is here.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js

The link will most likely break when the Blink and Chromium repositories get merged. I think src/third_party/WebKit will turn into src/blink.

Like I said, deep links into source code are doomed to get stale quickly!

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes and a place on the hall of fame of SO. By the way @PaulIrish, what's the source of the chronologic data? i.e: "Prototype then followed up four days later with their own". Sounds like this could be a best-seller; "Javascript: An unexpected journey".