# What is the difference between $ and $$

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the difference between `$` and `$$`? It seems like they both return a list of nodes, but `filter` isn't applicable to `$$` and throws an exception.
What are the other differences?

Comment: Maybe a q for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The first half of [Paul Irish's answer to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10308917/106224) (via @VisioN) seems to suit this one pretty well.

Comment: @Michael Durrant: I'm pretty sure not. (Then again, this was previously closed as "not constructive", which is even more ridiculous.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a variable name. `$$` is a different variable name.

jQuery assigns a function to the `$` variable.

jQuery does nothing (by default) to the `$$` variable (so it will be `undefined` unless something else assigns a value to it).

Comment: +1 for the incredibly in-depth explanation of the difference between `$` and `$$`. :-)

Comment: There wasn't much depth to be had, so I prefer to think of it as having "a high percentage of coverage".

Comment: Ha, nice. +2 if I could, just for the humor.