# Why am I able to use jQuery syntax in Chrome's JS console when current page doesn't have jQuery loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I thought one has to have jQuery source loaded first in order to use `$` to target elements. I was on a webpage that doesn't even include any scripts but somehow I was able to run `$('body')` inside the Javascript console and Chrome successfully returned its value.

Why didn't I get a syntax error like 'undefined token'? Thanks.

Comment: Was it using MooTools? MooTools also uses the `$` variable.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on http://www.this-page-intentionally-left-blank.org/

Comment: Maybe it's related to a plugin you have installed?

Comment: I just tried and here's the result: http://d.pr/i/cEcE

Comment: Tried with all plugins/extensions disabled and got same result.

Comment: Duplicate: [$ variable-in-chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks @jfrej that makes sense. I tried `jQuery('body')` and got 'jQuery not defined' so it's pretty clear now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before, Chrome had an alias to `document.getElementById` with the `$` variable.

[Recently](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92648) (probably on Chrome 23 release), it has been changed to an alias to `document.querySelector`.

So your code is the equivalent of `document.querySelector('body')`.

Answer (score 0):

As already alluded to in the comments by @Shmiddty, it is likely due to a plugin you have installed...

You can find out by running developer tools, select 'Sources' and look at both the Sources and Content Scripts panes - is something suspiciously like jQuery in there somewhere?

Comment: Nope, it's a Dev Tools function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-in-chrome

Comment: @jfrej The Dev Tools is only an alias to `getElementById`, using `$('body')` wouldn't work unless there is an element with the id `body`.

Comment: My bad. It seems like it also loads `body`. Weird.

Comment: Oh, interesting!  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @jfrej FWIW, this has recently been changed. Probably Chrome 23.