# What is the difference between $ and $$?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have been going through some jQuery functionality.

Can any one please give me some idea of what the difference is between the use of `$` and `$$`?

Comment: Could you share some code where you see it?

Comment: Can you provide examples of where you've seen `$` and `$$` being used as they relate to jquery?

Comment: `$$` has no significance to jQuery; its use is an arbitrary decision by whomever authored whatever it is your looking at.

Comment: I think you might be confusing jQuery and Mootools. Mootools does use the `$$` selector.

Comment: Are you sure your not looking at the Prototype library?  http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: "some" jQuery functionality like ... ?

Comment: Or, as my answer states, `$$` is an alias provided by browsers to `document.querySelectorAll`. (Just like `$` is an alias to `document.querySelector`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On jQuery documentation there is no `$$` statement. jQuery has a default selector with `$` character. Maybe this script uses another javascript package and has some conflicts with jQuery. In this case, you can use `jquery.NoConflict` to avoid this kind of problem, and set another jquery selector.

Something like:

```
var s = jQuery.noConflict();

// something with new jQuery selector
s("div p").hide();

// something with another library using $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

If your code has somethig like to avoid conflicts: `var $$ = jquery.noConfict();`, you can use $$ as a jquery selector:

```
$$("#element").method();
```

See more on the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 19):

`$` and `$$` will work on any web page (if jQuery is not included also) on Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers where `$` returns first element of selector passed.

Here,

$ is `document.querySelector`

$$ is `document.querySelectorAll`

They are native functions of Google Chrome and Firefox browsers, you can see `$` and `$$` definition in Safari as well.

Open [Google](http://google.com/) in any of Google Chrome, Firefox or Safari, and open Developer Tools to check these results... (why Google, because they won't use jQuery or Moo tools)

```js
$('div');  // returns first DIV in DOM
$$('div'); // returns all DIVs in DOM
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`jQuery` is an object provided by jQuery. `$` is another, which is just an alias to `jQuery`.

`$$` is not provided by jQuery. It's provided by other libraries, such as Mootools or Prototype.js.

More importantly, `$$` is also provided in the console of modern browsers as an alias to `document.querySelectorAll`. Except if it's overridden by another library. `$` is also provided in the same way, as an alias to `document.querySelector`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402776/why-am-i-able-to-use-jquery-syntax-in-chromes-js-console-when-current-page-does/13403311#13403311) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

$ AND $$ are mootools selectors and $ is also a jquery selector.

see jquery noconflict-mode

Answer (score 1):

**Short Anser:** `$$` is **NOT** defined in jQuery specifications, in addition the notation of single `$( )` - sign means you encapsulate things inside bracket to a jQuery object.

Thus, alias `$` is an abbreviation to say - i am using jQuery library, where as double `$$` is not defined in a standard jQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery functionality is encapsulated in the `jQuery` object, which is also accessible as `$`. The code you are examining might be using a different library (eg. Mootools), that uses a `$$` function.

Answer (score 1):

$$ has no significant in Jquery, however it is used within the prototype framework.

[Prototype $$](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/)

Also check that this is not a previous version of Jquery assigned using `noConflict`.

Search the code for `var $$` to find a possible assignment of an older jquery version.

```
var $$ = jquery.noConfict();
```