# Failed to execute $$ on 'CommandLineAPI'

Tags: jquery

I'm getting an error that I haven't seen before and not sure as to why

I'm looking for a specific element on a page using jQuery

`$(".bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text")` works as expected. However when I try to search the innerHTML of all of the results using `:contains()` I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text")
<span class="bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text ng-binding">Cold Prospect</span>
$(".bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text:contains('Cold')")
VM4277:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '.bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text:contains('Cold')' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: Can you post the source and any errors as text? That screenshot is too tiny to read, it's just smudges.

Comment: if you click on it, it should make it bigger in imgur. I'm injecting some code into a web page to find a button on a page to click.

Comment: That's not a solution. Just copy-paste the error as text and it'll be instantly readable for everyone, not just people who mess around and view it on Imgur.

Comment: ok,doing that now! thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is just jQuery? `$` is the jQuery selector. `$$` is some extension to it.

Comment: `$` is `querySelector` and `$$` is `querySelectorAll`. It seems that `$` will only select the first element of the results, vs `$$` will return the entire list.

Comment: oooh I see. I understand now. just using `$` with `:contains()` worked

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933157/what-is-the-difference-between-and).

Comment: nevermind, still getting the same error `$(".bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text:contains('Warm')")
VM4379:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute '$' on 'CommandLineAPI': '.bmr-dropdown-menu-item__text:contains('Warm')' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:1`