# How to traverse dom dot notation with a div element with an id

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to traverse the dom with just dot notation

e.g.
 document.body

Under body I have a div with id `mydiv`. I know about querySelector() or getElementById() but that's not my question. I simply want to open the JS console and using dot notation drill down into elements using dot notation.

```
document.body.#mydiv # doesnt work
```

Would like the console to return #mydiv with the ability to expand and look at it in Chrome

Comment: No. But in the Chrome inspector, there are a lot of ways to search for elements, and expand them, but not like this. It's also unclear **exactly** what are you trying to do, so please clarify the question, if you can.

Comment: I'm familiarizing myself with the dom. I have the JS console open and am exploring by typing `document.body` and when I press enter I see the body element and all of it's contents within the console. If I want to get more granular and drill down into the div element with id 'mydiv' that is a direct child of body, is there no way to do that?

Comment: Clearly, you are trying to do something with this result, but yet not discussing the main issue here. Typical like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please include the specific scenario which you are trying this.

Comment: @Sam You can do it, but as I've mentioned, not like that. First, `#` is invalid identifier name, so using it in dot notation is syntactically invalid in JS. Second, `document`'s `body` property is special (you can get the `<body>`, but you can't go deeper this way). You can use `.children`, to see a list of children of any DOM node, or `querySelector` to search for a selector, like `#mydiv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an element with id you can always use below in console

```
$('#myDiv');
```

or

```
$$('#myDiv')
```

This will show that element in console, from there you can see all details of that element.

This should also work with any selector

eg: Try below in this page

```
$$('.user-details')
```

You will see something like this

[image]

Comment: `$()` is not a JavaScript built-in function. What JavaScript library are you using?

Comment: @ElisByberi These are native functions of Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox browsers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933157/what-is-the-difference-between-and)

Comment: Warning: These functions only work when you call them from the Chrome DevTools Console. They won't work if you try to call them in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `firstElementChild`, `lastElementChild` or `children` to get to the next child.
`.children` will give you an array of all the children of a node. You can loop through it and find the div with specific id.
Here is an example

```
document.querySelector('body').children[2].firstElementChild.children[0]
```

This is get the 2nd child of the body's first child's first child.

`getElementById` is more easier and cleaner in your case.

Answer (score 0):

To traverse tree using dot notation you need to use `children` nodes

```js
console.log( myDiv.children[0].innerText );
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```