# What is the difference between $ of jQuery and $ of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery library is not used in google.com 
When we type `$` in Console of google.com and hit enter, we can see

```
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

But here in Stackoverflow, since jQuery library is used, when we type "$" we can see :

```
function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

What is the difference between the `$` we see in console for those where jQuery is not used and where Jquery is used?

Does one have more benefits than the other?
As per my knowledge, `$` is jQuery's shorthand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-in-chrome

Comment: Anyone can declare a variable `$`. Google could have one definition for it today and something else tomorrow. What's the point of this question?

Comment: have you hit the `$$` in stackoverflow?

Comment: "[Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does...](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)"

Comment: To know if jQuery library is used or not, i was using jQuery's shorthand $. But I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon practice to adopt `$` as an alias for

- `getQuerySelector`
- `getQuerySelectorAll`

`$` is a valid function name and it can name *any new function* or alias *any existing function*.