# How $ in javascript works and how to add functions

Tags: javascript

I've notice that window.$ or $ can be used without using jQuery.
 Is this already built in browsers?
 Why don't I see documentations about it?

I would like to add/create something like jQuery does without using jQuery at all.
Like

```
$(selector).slide = function(){ //something};
```

How do I accomplish this without the use of jQuery? 
Is there a way to override window.$ or create an instance perhaps?

I know how to use jQuery btw, just wanted to make something very simple and light.

Comment: No; `$` does not exist without jQuery.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-in-chrome

Comment: @SLaks not totally accurate...other libraries also use `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same of `document.querySelector` if jQuery is not used :

```
$(SELECTOR);
// are same if jQuery is not used
document.querySelector(SELECTOR);
```

note that `document.querySelector` returns the first `HTMLElement` which satisfies the SELECTOR.

IF you want to  get all elements , use `document.querySelectorAll` instead which is `$$`

```
$$(SELECTOR); // double dollar
// are same if jQuery is not used
document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR);
```

#### Firefox :

[image]

#### Chrome :

[image]

---

## PART 2 of question : Build something like jQuery :

The below example is a Proof Of Concept which handles only the first selected element .

```js
function $(selector){
  return new MyQuery(selector);
}

class MyQuery {
    constructor(selector) {
      this.element = document.querySelector(selector);
    }
     
    html() {
      if (! arguments.length )
        return this.element.innerHTML;
      else {
         this.element.innerHTML = arguments[0];
         return this; // !! important for call chaining
      }
    }
}


//-then -- Use it : 
console.log(
  $('section').html()
);

setTimeout(() => {
   $('section').html(' I am changed by MyQuery');
   console.log(
     $('section').html()
   );
}, 2500);
```

```html
<section>I want to be extracted by MyQuery</section>
```

Comment: That's only in Chrome DevTools; you can't do that in a page.

Comment: no no .. see firefox .. it is the same .. check my updated answer.

Comment: But it still only works in the dev tools.

Comment: emmm .. are u sure ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wazibufuga/edit?html,js,console,output