# How is JQuery getting in my developer console Webpack Babel ES6

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have as simple environment where I am using Webpack and ES6(Babel) to create a JavaScript Bundle. I do not have Jquery as a dependency(package.json), I am not requiring it or importing it anywhere.  I am not sure how I have access to **$** in my chrome developer console.
[Screenshot from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zooX.png)

However when I try to do console.log($) from the webpage code it show me an error as shown in image above.(index:23)

I am confuse what's going on. here is my package.json (not sure if any other library is including jquery )

[Package.Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohFTx.png)

Here is the index.html where my bundle is getting injected

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>  Widget</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>


</head>
<body>
        <h1> Would you look at this awesome page</h1>
        <div id="app">
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </p>
        </div>

</body>
<script>

    setTimeout(console.log($),5000);
</script>
</html>
```

Here is my webpack.babel.js

```js
/**
 * Created by desaim on 7/10/2017.
 */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';


const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});
const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname,'src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname,'dist')
};
const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND;

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
    NODE_ENV:JSON.stringify('production')
  }
});


const base = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
    publicPath:'/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},
      {
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:(?:pn|jpe?)g|gif)$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
      }
    ]
  },
};
const developmentConfig = {
  devtool:'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: PATHS.build,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    historyApiFallback:true
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]


};
const productionConfig = {
  devtool:'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,productionPlugin]
};

export default Object.assign({},base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
)
```

The console.log in setimeout is failing

Comment: where is your jQuery imported?

Comment: It is not that Y I am confused. I am using webpack to bundle my JavaScript, not sure if that is making $ appear

Comment: If the web page does not assign anything to `$`, the chrome devtools will provide a few debugging functions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47290972/7486612

Comment: Is this Native to Chrome? I tried IE11 I am getting similar behavior