# JQuery Input .change() is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Testing this syntax in the dev tools console in prep to add it to some javascript. Why is it that the JQuery selector correctly returns the `input`, but then you can't invoke the `.change()` or even a `.val()` method on it?

[image: .trigger('change')]

Comment: Are you using jQuery? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-dollar-sign-in-chrome

Comment: @AndyRay this is a 3rd party web page. I'm using Power Automate to try to automate some functions for a client. So what I think you're asking, does that web page load a JQuery library? I guess not now that I look at the source, I can't find any references for 'Jquery' or '$', etc. I guess I was just surprised that the original selector worked.