# Why is $ defined, even in about:blank?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I've opened a new tab in Firefox and a blank tab in Chrome. When I type `$` into the console, the variable is already defined. What is this, why does it exist, and what does it do?

[image]

If it is jQuery, it must be a very old/minimal version. `$('body')` returns the body element, but `$('body').text()` throws `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function`.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-dollar-sign-in-chrome

Comment: @j08691 yep, thanks for the link. I tried googling first but nothing relevant came up :(

Answer (score 0):

By default, in the browser console, `$` is an alias for [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).  Although, it is redefined by jQuery, and because of that the `$` has become strongly associated with jQuery due to its popularity.

So, sticking with the `about:blank` example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use one of these two options to select an element:

```js
$("body")
document.querySelector("body")
```

And both will return the same object, the `body` element.

Comment: _"By default `$` is an alias for `querySelector`."_ Do you have a reference for this statement? I don't think it's correct.

Comment: @AdamJenkins That's a reference of a Chrome Console. This answer doesn't mention the Chrome Console and contains a link to MDN.

Comment: @jabaa doesn’t mean the answer or my comment are wrong. The answer was referencing the function that is aliased by $ in the dev console, you asked for a reference and I provided a more appropriate one

Comment: @AdamJenkins I'm asking for a reference that show that `$` is an alias for `querySelector` in general. _"Although, it is redefined by jQuery, and because of that the $ has become strongly associated with jQuery due to its popularity."_ This statement is even worse. jQuery existed before dev tools existed.

Comment: @jabaa In addition the chrome reference above, here’s Firefox reference: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html. Browser vendors are consistent in their developer console experience. You’re welcome to find the reference to safari developer console aliases yourself

Comment: @AdamJenkins It's an alias in dev tools. But not in the browser. The answer doesn't explain that it only works in the dev tools.

Comment: The original question referenced the console, this answer answered the question that was asked in the context that it was asked in. You’re not wrong, but a bit pedantic. I’ve edited the answer to clearly state what the author IMO, obviously meant

Comment: @AdamJenkins Could you also fix the second sentence. It makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you @AdamJenkins for your fixes, I should've been more clear in the original answer.  As for the second sentence, I feel it adds an important note about context when discussing the `$` function.