# What is the "$$" variable/object used in Google sites' JavaScript such as Gmail, Reader, and Search?

Tags: javascript, gmail, userscripts, dollar-sign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the source of the double-dollar sign selector query function in Chrome /Ffirefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981211/what-is-the-source-of-the-double-dollar-sign-selector-query-function-in-chrome)

I noticed that many major Google sites (webapps) such as Search, Gmail, and Reader define not just a `$` object but also a `$$` object.

I'm not sure what the former is but the latter has at least a selector function similar to jQuery.

`$$` is not full jQuery itself though. I can do things like `$$('main')` but not `$$('main').text()`.

Does anyone know what this `$$` object is? Is it a cutdown version of jQuery? Is it the Sizzle selector engine? Is it some other framework which looks a bit similar to jQuery?

Is it documented anywhere?

Bonus questions:

- Is there some other object on Google sites with other jQuery functions?
- What is the `$` object they use?

---

Background: I've had some trouble getting jQuery to work in Google Chrome user scripts (like Greasemonkey) on Google sites no matter whether I inject jQuery into the sites using script tags or inject my userscript code into their pages to use whatever frameworks or libraries they might already include.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981211/what-is-the-source-of-the-double-dollar-sign-selector-query-function-in-chrome

Comment: @elclanrs: I think you're right. I am using Chrome and I found that there are both `$` and `$$` objects even in `about:blank`!

Comment: I think latest Chrome redefined the meaning of `$` and `$$` a little bit, so it might not be the same as Firebug, but yes, those are browser variables AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't use jQuery in its webapps. Instead, Google uses its own javascript library, called **Closure Library** in almost all of its webapps(mail, docs, map, plus). This library has been open sourced in 2009 on google code. [This is the link](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/)

What's more, Google has written a javascript compiler(or **optimizer**, to be more precise) called **Closure Compiler** to use together with the closure library.

There is a full page on developers.google.com about the **closure tools**. [This is the link](https://developers.google.com/closure/)

Comment: I knew that there was some kind of JavaScript compiler called Closure but I didn't know some of the other details. Thanks!