# What is JSTH_keys()?

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I open a console on my browser (Firefox 43) and type `keys`, it returns a function: `JSTH_keys()`.

I searched all over Google, but I couldn't find any documentation on this.

So, what is `JSTH_keys()`? What is it for? What does it do? What does `JSTH` stand for?

Comment: It's part of the [Mozilla dev tools](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/B2G/gecko/browser/devtools/webconsole/HUDService.jsm#4651). Nothing that would be available to normal JS code, not part of a web page, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I see from the source code that it appears to be a wrapper to Object.keys. Also I've found that Chrome also supports the keys function. As for the other part of my question, any idea what JSTH stands for?

Comment: [JSTermHelper](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/B2G/gecko/browser/devtools/webconsole/HUDService.jsm#4549)

Comment: Of course. So obvious now (from your first link). Thank you!

Comment: @PaulRoub Funny how despite being part of the dev tools, and not the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) (DOM), it still breaks code, should you accidentally use it as a variable, like say, an *array*, because it doesn't let you re-define it for some reason, even though it really *ought to* since `keys` by itself is non-standard in respect to the DOM. Let's just hope they don't accidentally do this with `$`, otherwise they'll break jQuery.

Comment: Also, I think this is a good question, and that it doesn't deserve the downvote that it got. I think the "Google-fu" bit might have struck a nerve with someone. Call it a hunch, but I went ahead and edited the question to be more *to-the-point*.

Comment: If you don't want to [self-answer this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I'd suggest to close as a duplicate of [What is the source of the double-dollar sign selector query function in Chrome/Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8981211/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulRoub for the answer.

JSTH stands for the JSTermHelper and is part of [Mozilla's development tools](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/B2G/gecko/browser/devtools/webconsole/HUDService.jsm#4549). The keys function simply wraps the call to the function Object.keys which returns an array containing the names of all properties of the object.