# Javascript Console: What does `$$` mean?

Tags: javascript, inspect

When i type `$` into the javascript console of an HTML document which includes the jQuery Library, the autocompleter gives the following variables: `$` (thats clear to me, it transforms something into its jQuery equivalent) `$x`, `$u`, `$_`, `$0`, `$$`. The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) gives no results when i search for these variables. They do not even seem to be contained in jquery.js. Do these variables have any relevant meaning?

---

Edit: OK, i learned, this is not related to jQuery. For the records, [what is $$? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311234/javascript-what-is) is not found when searching for `"$"` or `Javascript "$"` on Stackoverflow or on Google. Thats why i asked this question.

Comment: Have you tried it on a document that *doesn't* include jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these are special functions available from the Chrome Command Line, for example;

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

Comment: Thanks a lot. These variables do also exist in Firefox. I guess their meaning is the same?

Comment: Yeah, I guess all the browser vendors have their own interpretations/implementations but they end up to be pretty much the same. Makes development a little bit easier again. ;) Good luck!